# upload files using form Text input type

Tags: php, html, forms

Presently I am using , `type="file"`  for uploading files. But my use case is to upload from text box itself with given complete file path.

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In submit form page:

```
<?php move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ?>
```

I want to specify file path in a **textbox** , from there i want upload the image. How can i accomplish it ?

Comment: Have you thought about **vulnerabilities** for paths including `..` and being uploaded executable files?

Comment: @CertaiN: I will check file types before uploading the files

Comment: @CertaiN : do you have an idea to do this ? Actually i will be getting file paths from an excel. with that reference i will upload the files. So now i wanted to know whether it is achievable through textbox. if yes, then i can upload from file paths mentioned in excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my knowledge you can't upload files with a textbox from the client's computer. Otherwise, it would be very easy to steal any file from the client, since textboxes are editable with JavaScript. I hope I understood your question correctly.

*EDIT: Do you mean uploading from your computer, or from an URL? The second one can be accomplished.*

Comment: I dont understand. then every website is risk in today's world as every website has textbox.

Comment: No, I mean **IF** textboxes would be able to upload files from the computer of the client... but they can't.

Comment: I am asking textbox to upload. My Submit form page will do it. I just need to pass the path through textbox

Comment: Okay, but do you want to upload a file from **computer**, or from an **URL**?

Comment: from computer system path

Comment: That cannot be accomplished. If you don't pass the file in a file input, then the file won't be uploaded. So you can't upload a file from a computer from a textbox.

Comment: I believe nothing is impossible in this world. let me wait for other's solution

Comment: A phrase heard by many developers the world over. Usually from a project manager who has no scope of technical implementations. @icore is right. You can not upload a file without using type="file", otherwise its going to post just the piece of text.

Comment: I am not a manager :) but the phrase was told by The Great Napoleon!

Comment: What if I want to upload text in the textfield through input type file?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function h($str) {
    return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

if (
    isset($_POST['path'], $_FILES['upfile']['error']) &&
    is_int($_FILES['upfile']['error']) &&
    is_string($_POST['path'])
) {

    try {

        $deep = 0;
        foreach (explode('/', $_POST['path']) as $i => $hierarchy) {
            if ($deep > 9) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Hierarchy is too deep');
            }
            if ($hierarchy === '') {
                if ($_POST['path'] !== '' && $i === 0) { 
                    throw new RuntimeException('Absolute path is not allowed');
                }
                continue;
            }
            if ($hierarchy === '.') {
                continue;
            }
            if (!preg_match('/\A(?!\.)[\w.-]++(?<!\.)\z/', $hierarchy)) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Invalid directory name: ' . h($hierarchy));
            }
            if (!is_dir($hierarchy)) {
                if (!mkdir($hierarchy)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to create directory: ' . h($hierarchy));
                }
                $msgs[] = 'Created directory "' . h($hierarchy) . '"';
                chmod($hierarchy, 0777);
            }
            chdir($hierarchy);
            ++$deep;
        }
        switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new RuntimeException('File is not choosed');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new RuntimeException('File is too large');
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown error occurred');
        }
        if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
            throw new RuntimeException('File is too large');
        }
        if (!$info = getimagesize($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'])) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid image file');
        }
        if (false === array_search(
            $info['mime'],
            array(
                'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'png' => 'image/png',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
            ),
            true
        )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unsupported image format');
        }
        if (!preg_match('/\A(?!\.)[\w.-]++(?<!\.)\z/', $_FILES['upfile']['name'])) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid filename: ' . h($_FILES['upfile']['name']));
        }
        if (!move_uploaded_file(
            $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['upfile']['name']
        )) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to save uploaded file');
        }

        $msgs[] = 
            'Uploaded successfully: ' .
            ($_POST['path'] === '' ? '.' : $_POST['path']) .
            '/' .
            $_FILES['upfile']['name']
        ;

    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {

        $msgs[] = $e->getMessage();

    }

}

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hierarchical Image Uploading</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($msgs)): ?>
  <ul>
<?php foreach ($msgs as $msg): ?> 
    <li><?=$msg?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Select file (Directory name and filename must match <strong>'/(?!\A\.*+\z)\A(?!\.)[\w.-]++(?&lt;!\.)\z/'</strong>)</legend>
      Directory path: <input type="text" name="path" value=""><br />
      Filename(JPEG, PNG, GIF): <input type="file" name="upfile"><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me also try, Mine is Linux

Comment: Is this only form submit page data ?

Comment: still you are using `<input type="file" name="upfile">` ?